# Calculation in laravel eloquent query

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have a table with 2 columns and I want to get the columns that when the difference is made, the answer is greater than 500
Like this:

> colOne - colTow

Can I do something like this is laravel eloquent

```
return $query->where('colOne','-','colTow','>=500')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

`->whereRaw('colOne - colTow >= ?',[500])`
**or**
`->where(Db::raw('colOne - colTow') , '>=' ,500)`

Read this: [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions).